# Recommendations for a hardy, IP67 arm

Tags: ros, manipulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm looking for an IP67 arm for a mobile robot in a harsh environment. Some other wishes are:

- ROS compatability
- Small controller (must fit on a ~900mm x 900mm platform)
- Reach >500mm
- At least 5 DOF

So far, I've just found the [Fanuc LR Mate 200iD](http://www.fanucamerica.com/cmsmedia/datasheets/LR%20Mate%20200iD%20Series_187.pdf) and possibly an [Oceaneering Terabot](http://www.oceaneering.com/space-systems/robotics-and-automation/terabot/). But I think the Fanuc's controller is huge. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246511/recommendations-for-a-hardy,-ip67-arm/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
Not an answer, but the Fanuc R-30iB Mate controller would actually seem to fit your constraints: regular cabinet is 470x402x400mm (WxDxH) max, OpenAir is even smaller: 370x350x356mm (WxDxH) max. They're 40 and 20 Kg respectively. Which controller have you seen?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
Control interfaces offered by the Terabot are way better than those for the Fanuc though. External motion control on Fanucs is not too good. But do ask Fanuc about that.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2016-10-31**:
Thank you for the advice, @gvdhoorn! I got a quote from Fanuc and the price seems good (better than I expected). Unfortunately the smallest controller is not available so it would be the 470x402x400mm one. Can you tell me more about the weaknesses of the ROS-I Fanuc driver?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
It's not the ros-i driver per se: Fanucs just don't really have options for external motion control, when compared to vendors like KUKA, ABB, Denso, Mitsubishi, etc. All those vendors have 100Hz+ joint position control *at least*. The closest thing Fanuc has is something called DPM ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
.. Dynamic Path Modification. But that is Cartesian only, and is really limited. With sufficient time & effort, DPM could perhaps be used to create an external interface with sufficient performance, but even then, it would only be position control. Velocity, effort or impedance are not possible ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
.. at least not when you want to exert any influence over it from an external entity. Everything *as far as I know* of course, but I've spent some time looking into this. If you can prove me wrong, please do so, as it would allow me to improve the ROS-I driver as well. If you have the option, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
.. and you want to control your robot externally (which I suspect you want to do, as you list "ROS compatibility"), then, if you want to stay with industrial robots, I'd go with any of the other vendors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
An example: the [KUKA Agilus](http://www.kuka-robotics.com/en/products/industrial_robots/small_robots) (KR 3, 6, 10, etc) are IP67, and when used with RSI, have a proper (250Hz) position control interface. ROS-I pkg: [kuka_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
Apparently they have a waterproof version of the Agilus: [KR AGILUS Waterproof](http://www.kuka-robotics.com/en/pressevents/news/NN_131217_KR_AGILUS_Waterproof.htm).

I'd really like you to use Fanuc, but depending on your requirements, other mfgs might be more realistic right now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
Please ask Fanuc about their external motion control options btw. It'd be nice if I'm completely wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
O, and I'm assuming you'd want some sort of reactive control here. For simple pick-and-place type work, the current driver is ok (but could still certainly be improved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I appreciate @gvdhoorn's advice. We were leaning towards a Fanuc LR Mate until finding that UR sells [protective suits](https://www.universal-robots.com/plus/product/Roboworld-Protective-Suits-for-UR32c-UR5-and-UR10-22567/). And we already know and love UR's ROS interface, so I think we'll go with that.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-11**:
Thanks for letting us know what you eventually chose.

> And we already know and love UR's ROS interface [..]

Just to clarify: you mean the ROS driver(s) that exist(s) for UR hw. UR had no hand in them :).